# ActiveModel::Serializer: Choose JSON encoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to decide which JSON encoder ActiveModel::Serializer uses? It seems that JSON encoding takes forever, and I'd like to try some other encoder.

Comment: i don't see anything about switching out the used encoder, but if you dig into the code you might find a way to monkey patch it - however, performance issues are addressed in the [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#design-and-implementation-guidelines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Rails won't allow you to do that by default, you can use [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) and include this at your Gemfile:

```
gem 'oj'
gem 'oj_mimic_json'
```

And it will definitely be faster in these cases.

You can read more about the JSON troubles in Rails below:

- [ActiveRecord::Base.extend kills JSON performance](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9212)
- [when freedom patches fight, nobody wins](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/pull/138#issuecomment-24468223)

And while you're at it, run away from `ActiveModel::Serializer` and just build your own presenter layer to produce the JSON and be happy.

Comment: Hmm. Does this mean that I have to manually call Oj.dump? Or will oj_mimic_json be enough?

Comment: When `mimic_JSON` is called `oj` becomes the `JSON` gem so Rails is forced to use it.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares `gem 'oj_mimic_json'` appears to be working great!  Any recommendations on resources for serializer alternatives?